# How do I build up a Neo4j graph from hundreds of thousands of events?

Tags: neo4j

We have an event sourced application and is thinking about adding neo4j to the question to view some relations. I think the use case is really good, but the problem is that if I would replay every event one by one it would take to much time to build up the graph. So what's the best to rebuild a graph from ~1.000.000 events? The resulting graph is approx. 100.000 nodes and a lot of relations. The first naive attempt was to do it one by one but it takes way to much time since this is something that we might want to do more than one time.

Is the best approach to build an inmemory list of all nodes and then build a large cypher query for all nodes and one for the relationships? Or is the best way to use the batch API?

In an ideal situation the logic for rebuilding should be the same as when I handle the event one by one but for live handling a "commit" should be done after each event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is to keep the same logic as in the application lifecycle for the events, and you use Cypher in your application, then you'll have no choice to handle it with the Transactional Cypher endpoint.

It is barely doable, while LOAD CSV and the BATCH api will give you more performance.

I have an application where I write ~1250 Cypher statements per Cypher transaction, each transaction takes approximately between 0.2 and 0.3 seconds.

Some little tips to achieve this time rate :

Do small statements : if you need to write a lot, it is better for eg to have 10 small statements like `MATCH (n1), (n2) MERGE (n1)-[:FOLLOW]->(n2)` than a big statement with 10 merges.

Profile your queries and make sure that all the indexes are correct

Stay between 500-1000 statements per transaction.

Allow sufficient memory to your database for the time of the bulk load.

Comment: Thanks for a great reply. That was the answer I got from Neo4j as well. If I can read the events sufficiently fast and build up the statements fast I should be down to a couple of minutes to process all events if you estimates is correct.

Comment: I did a test yesterday for a 1 million nodes insert, 135seconds, 1k statements per tx, 8gb heap of ram

Comment: I will, but the transaction part was probably the missing piece for me. I do have one more problem and that is I might have to do some lookups while doing the inserts and that might cause some performance issue. One solution to that is to keep everything in memory while catching up, and the switch to lookup. Either way, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use [LOAD CSV](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html) for my initial load, and then use individual or batched `INSERT` statements for the drip-feed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Might be an option, but I would rather use the same logic for both live write and when doing initial load since the event handling should be the same for both.